# Android repeat CountDownTimer until end foreach loop

Tags: java, android, timer, foreach, countdowntimer

I want to repeat a `CountDownTimer` within a `for` loop until its execution complete. But `CountDownTimer` executes first index of `for` loop and it can not repeat again for next index.

```
for (final Question questionData : questionSet) {
            setUI(questionData);
            startTimer();
}
private void setUI(Question questionData) {
    question.setText(questionData.getQuestion());
    ch1.setText(questionData.getC1());
    ch2.setText(questionData.getC2());
    ch3.setText(questionData.getC3());

}

private void startTimer(){
    int interval = 10000;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(interval, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setText("seconds remaining: "
                    + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            time.setText("done!");
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Here `questionSet` has two index.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "until execution complete" what do you actually mean?

Comment: until execution complete of for loop

Comment: your technical vocabulary is mysterious... still dont know what you mean...

Comment: it seems like you want to wait till the timer finishes and then ask other question. then i feel for loop wont work. implement timer mechanism such that after first run of timer finishes timer itself change question and then restart timer again.

Comment: Are You trying to let two countdowntimers run at the same time? A for loop executes successively in a very short time, so what´s Your intention behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution.

```
for (final Question questionData : questionSet) {
            tempQuestionSet.add(questionData);
            setUI(questionData);
            startTimer();
            break;
}
private void setUI(Question questionData) {
    question.setText(questionData.getQuestion());
    ch1.setText(questionData.getC1());
    ch2.setText(questionData.getC2());
    ch3.setText(questionData.getC3());

}

private void startTimer(){
    int interval = 10000;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(interval, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setText("seconds remaining: "
                    + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            time.setText("done!");
            final Question question = getQuestionSet();
            if(question == null){
                countDownTimer.cancel();
            }else{
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        setUI(question);
                    }
                });
                countDownTimer.start();
            }

        }
    }.start();

}

private Question getQuestionSet(){
    Question newQuestion = null;
    for (final Question questionData : questionSet) {
        if(tempQuestionSet.contains(questionData)){         
        }
        else{
            tempQuestionSet.add(questionData);
            return questionData;
        }
    }
    return newQuestion;
}
```